# posicion Fixed en navegador móvil , boton flotante

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, navegador-web

Tengo una consulta, he buscado en diferentes foros pero no he logrado resolver un problema que se me presenta con  la creación de un Botón flotante.

Mi problema consiste en que cuando ingreso al sitio desde un dispositivo móvil, este botón no se visualiza,  he intentado utilizar las herramientas de chrome para
poder detectar el problema pero a pesar que cambie el modo de vista desde el ordenador todo esta OK.

Boton: 
Html

```
<a href="https://www.otrapagina.com" target="_blank" class="scroll">
<b data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Mensaje X" >
 <img  style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" src="images/001.png">
</b>
</a>
```

Css:

```
.scroll {
    display: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

---

```
@media only screen and (max-width:435px) {
    .scroll {
       font-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

Js

/* Scroll To Top */

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {
    $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
     $('.scroll').fadeIn();
 } else {
    $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
     $('.scroll').fadeOut();
 }
 });


$('.scroll-to-top').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
  return false;
  });
```

Esto es todo lo que utilizo para este botón flotante, como dato adicional les comento que este botón es el "`.scroll`", el el js hay un "`.scroll-to-top`" pero ese es para volver al inicio de la pagina y **funciona perfectamente**, tanto en ordenador como en móvil.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]